# jHipster: Как хранить критерии поиска/фильтрации?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

В проекте jHipster у меня есть несколько контроллеров EntityNameResource.java 
типа такого:

***ClientsRatingResource.java***

```
  @GetMapping("/clients-ratings")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<ClientsRatingDTO>> getAllClientsRatings(ClientsRatingCriteria criteria) {
        log.debug("REST request to get ClientsRatings by criteria: {}", criteria);
        List<ClientsRatingDTO> entityList = clientsRatingQueryService.findByCriteria(criteria);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(entityList);
    }

    @GetMapping("/clients-ratings/count")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Long> countClientsRatings(ClientsRatingCriteria criteria) {
        log.debug("REST request to count ClientsRatings by criteria: {}", criteria);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(clientsRatingQueryService.countByCriteria(criteria));
    }
```

***ClientsRatingCriteria.java***

```
public class ClientsRatingCriteria implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private LongFilter id;

private StringFilter clientName;

private IntegerFilter visitCount;

private LongFilter paSum;
 .........
getter and setters...

}
```

Я хочу хранить критерии поиска/фильтрации для каждого пользователя и для каждого метода. Как вариант хранить это в базе данных в таблице типа:

```
Long user_id;
Long method_id;
String criteria;
```

Но идея кажется не совсем удачной, т.к нужно,чтобы каждый метод генерил свой уникальный номер,и главное,что всё это хранится в базе данных.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть достаточно добавить кэширование? Повесить на методы findByCriteria, countByCriteria @Cachable, настроить в аннотации ключи для кэширования и, если нужна персистентность, использовать кэш-провайдер с дампом на диск (ehCache).

Comment: Пока сделал как написал в вопросе. Надо будет опробовать Ваш вариант. Спасибо за ответ!